# How to handel max limit of sql connections?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I have a small php chatting application. It has a lot of ajax scripts that make requests to database.

One runs every half a second to show chat on screen. second runs every second to check online users, third runs whenever a message is typed.

In short, it needs to make thousands of database requests which is why I can't host it on any cheap webhosting site as they keep blocking my account for max limit of sql requests.

Is there any way I can reduce the number of connections, maybe by using some other method? Will WebSocket help? I don't know.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Change your architecture?  Have a your clients communicate with a web service, that web service only needs a single connection to the database, or possible a single pool of a reasonable number of connections.  There are a bazillion frameworks for Ajax Chat Systems, look through those rather than re-inventing your own wheel.

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the response. Could you please suggest some of the good framworks?